# Accessing network shares in Reflected method calls

Tags: c#, reflection

We have a method that accesses a network share. This method works fine when called directly, but we get a System.IO.IOException when it is called via reflecton. It appear that the user context is not available to the reflected code (see stack trace below). Is there a way to prevent this?

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by 
the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.IOException: Logon failure:
unknown user name or bad password.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, 
String userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean includeFiles,
Boolean includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption)
at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(String path, String searchPattern, 
SearchOption searchOption)
```

this works

```
   Library.Class obj =new Library.Class();
   obj.Execute(serverPath);
```

this does not work

```
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"pathTo\Library.dll");
    Type type = assembly.GetType("Library.Class");
    MethodInfo executeMethod = type.GetMethod("Execute");
    object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);
    object[] parameterArray = new object[] { serverPath};
    executeMethod.Invoke(classInstance, parameterArray);
```

Where Library.Class.execute is defined as

```
public void Execute(string serverPath){
   string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(serverPath, 
                          "1.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (var directory in directories) {
        Console.WriteLine(directory);    
    }
}
```

and `serverPath` is a network share that required the user enter credentials.

-----**Update 1**-------

This appears to be somewhat environmental--I have at least one test machine where everything works. I'll be doing some more testing to determine what differences matter.

Comment: Does `LoadFrom` (instead of `LoadFile`) behave any differently?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx `LoadFile does not load files into the LoadFrom context, and does not resolve dependencies using the load path, as the LoadFrom method does`

Comment: That is useful information, but I don't think the issue had to do with `LoadFrom` vs `LoadFile` since in the actual code, the Library.dll is in the same folder as the executing application. Also, the problem mysteriously stopped happening today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been some sort of fluke environmental issue. We have not been able to reproduce the problem since the test machine was restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try these to get the current directory:

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Comment: My sample wasn't clear--the directory inspected is not the current directory, but rather a fully qualified network share, e.g. \\machine\share$\dir.